# Redirect loop due to htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The problem I'm having is that the first URL works and the second one doesn't.

http://www.example.com/podcasts
http://www.example.com/podcast

They're both HTML files, so adding .html to the second one will make it work. It's only when the html extension is stripped away (which is what I want to happen) that the redirect problem appears.

I think the issue is that "podcast" is both a folder and an html file. In other words, there is a folder called "podcast" and there is also a file called podcast.html, the extension of which is automatically stripped away (which was my intention).

So how can I fix this redirect issue? I would like the folder and the html to still have the same names and the html extension to be be stripped away, as it is now.

Here's a copy of my .htaccess file (edit: added L flags)

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

#removing trailing slash 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L] 

#non www to www 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 

#shtml 

AddType text/html .html 
AddHandler server-parsed .html 

#html 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L] 

#index redirect 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Pretty sure that the RewriteRule pertaining to %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f is causing the issue. The loop doesn't occur for a 404 error.

Ideas?

Comment: Both URLs you provided are almost the same except the first one has an additional "s" at the end. Is that a typo?

Comment: What is the input URL and what is/are the URLs you're being redirected to? (See Net inspector in Chrome / Firebug)

Comment: @holodoc No, that's not a typo. The idea is that "podcast" is both a folder and an html file, so it doesn't work, while "podcasts" is only an html file, therefore it has no redirect issues.

Comment: Also, add the `L` flag along with `R` flags; test with empty browser cache. This should eliminate some potential problems (and will introduce more problems).

Comment: @SalmanA Adding the L flags didn't help. Hmm.

Comment: One thing you might want to change is the last rule to: `RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.pavlinaplus.com/ [R=301,L]`, since you're redirecting again because the www is missing.

Comment: It won't, it wasn't suppose to. Do you now get infinite redirects or internal server error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this under your HTML section.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Your `-f` flag will prevent files from being considered in the rule, but this will exclude directories.

Comment: Add that RewriteCond to your trailing slash section as well. That would probably interfere, because the server tries to convert a directory name into a directory path (meaning it adds the trailing slash, then you remove it, then it adds it, then you remove it again).

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help. Except... it's not showing the podcast.html page, it's showing the raw index of the folder...